# Getting all the combinations of colors in a list?

Tags: search, prolog, logic

I have three possible colors: red, green, blue.

I have an initial list: [blue, blue, blue, blue].

I essentially need to create a search algorithm which finds a given list `Find` (which is also a list containing four colors). This is what the skeleton of the search algorithm looks like:

```
look(Find):- search([red, red, red, red], Find).

search([A,B,C,D], [A,B,C,D]):- do-something(A,B,C,D).

search(Node, Find):-
  successor(Node, Next),
  search(Next, Find).
```

My problem is with defining `successor`. How can I find a successor which I am sure that I have not visited before until I find one that is equal to the list `Find` - especially when I am not using the domain ({red, blue, green}) in the predicate. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily generate all the possibilites of 4 colors using `member/2` and `maplist/2`:

```
% give me a list of 4 fresh variables
% select a member of [red,blue,green] for each item of L, backtrackably

length(L,4),                                   
maplist([I]>>(member(I,[red,blue,green])),L).
```

The above is actually the same as

```
L=[L0,L1,L2,L3],
member(L0,[red,blue,green]),
member(L1,[red,blue,green]),
member(L2,[red,blue,green]),
member(L3,[red,blue,green]).
```

Watch out for the combinatorial explosion.

## In case a "stateless next" is preferred.

We want to derive the next red-green-blue combination from an existing one!

Let's use CLP(FD) to implement a bijective mapping between list-of-colors and numbers.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

rgbnumber(red,0).
rgbnumber(blue,1).
rgbnumber(green,2).

rgbnumberlist([L0,L1,L2],N) :- 
   rgbnumber(L0,N0), N0 in 0..2,
   rgbnumber(L1,N1), N1 in 0..2,
   rgbnumber(L2,N2), N2 in 0..2,
   N #= N0+N1*3+N2*3*3.

rgbnext(Current,Next,Wrap) :- 
   rgbnumberlist(Current,N),
   succ(N,Nx),
   Nxm is (Nx mod (3*3*3)), % Beware precedence: mod is as strong as *
   (Nx > Nxm -> Wrap = true ; Wrap = false),
   rgbnumberlist(Next,Nxm).
```

And thus:

```
?- rgbnext([red,red,red],A,Wrap).
A = [blue, red, red],
Wrap = false ;
false.

?- rgbnext([blue,red,red],A,Wrap).
A = [green, red, red],
Wrap = false ;
false.

?- rgbnext([green,red,red],A,Wrap).
A = [red, blue, red],
Wrap = false ;
false.

?- rgbnext([green,green,green],A,Wrap).
A = [red, red, red],
Wrap = true ;
false.
```

Now you can use this to find the next state from a current one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is a cool trick. I have two extra questions: firstly, is there any simple way of doing this without using maplist? Secondly (and more importantly), how do I impliment this in my successor predicate in such a way that no combination of colors that has been checked will not be checked again? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do it without `maplist/2` but this is done either by hardcoding the length of `L` as shown above or by rolling your own version of `maplist/2`, which recurses down `L` and constrains each list position to a value by calling `member/2`. Nothing to win here.

Comment: Now that you have a "generator" for all the combinations, you will not need to call successor recursively. You just call a maplist, then verify whether the colors are what you want. If not, you fail the verification, Prolog backtracks to the maplist and generates the next color-list, which is then everified again etc.: `search(X) :- generate_with_maplist(X), verify(X), format("Found solution ~q",[X]).`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am meant to keep the skeleton of the algorithm the same, and only define successor accordingly. This is meant to be a simple predicate, but I do not see how it can be done simply. If you have any ideas on how to do that, I would be happy to hear them. Nevertheless,  the solution you've given me is very interesting, even though I can't use it. Thanks again!

Comment: Added a "next" predicate. Instead of the inefficient one, this is the efficent one. It also uses CLP(FD). Hit some snag in the modulo computation, was going crazy...

Comment: Wow, that is really clever. I considered associating every color with a number, but I figured that would be too much of an imperative-programming way of thinking about it (I am rather new to Prolog if that wasn't obvious). The rest I wouldn't have thought of. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!